# Reading Multiple JSON objects in java

Tags: java, json

```
{"phone":1234,"name":"rose","key":1,"country":"india"} 
{"phone":6789,"name":"jasmine","key":2,"country":"india"}
```

while reading this type of json data ,I'm getting this error:

```
Unexpected token LEFT BRACE({) at position 54.
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:146)
    at org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser.parse(JSONParser.java:92)
```

Could anyone please help me resolve this error?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have 2 lines of JSON. Each line is a valid JSON object/document in of itself, however if you pass both lines together then it would not be a valid JSON document. Your options are

1. Read each line as a separate entry and invoke the JSON parser on that line to produce a JSON object.
2. Use an array to process both lines:

   [
   {"phone":1234,"name":"rose","key":1,"country":"india"},
   {"phone":6789,"name":"jasmine","key":2,"country":"india"}
   ]